# Subscript with Exponent (which is correct)

Tags: math-mode

Lets say I want to type `$i_0$` raised to the power `$p$`.

Which is the correct way:

- `$i_0^p$` (the simplest)
- `${i_0}^p$`
- `${i^p}_0$`

I think they appear slightly differently.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last is wrong, the middle one `${i_0}^p$` has some appeal as being logically closer to the mathematical meaning, however TeX is fundamentally a typesetting system not a semantic math markup, and the conventional setting would be to put the sub and superscript on the same base, to give a tighter horizontal spacing so `$i_0^p` (or in strictly correct latex syntax, `i_{0}^{p}` which produces the same thing).